# Using IAM Role to allow access to MySQL database on RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an IAM Role, myRole, for my project. I have an RDS server with a MySQL instance on it. The MySQL instance requires a username and password, however I don't want to pass these in as plaintext via command line, nor store them somewhere for retrieval later.

What I would like to do is somehow use the IAM Role as authentication in order to be able to perform backups, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible. IAM is for AWS resources. As related to RDS you would use IAM to give someone permission to create or modify an RDS server. The MySQL database engine doesn't know that it is running on AWS and doesn't know anything about IAM roles, so it can't use that for user authentication. You have to stick with username/passwords for authentication to the database.

**Update 12/13/2017:** [You can now use IAM authentication for RDS MySQL and Aurora](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html).

Comment: I figured as much, and I guess it's more sterile that way. It would be so nice if AWS roles included 3rd party authentication plugins e.g. MySQL, WordPress, 2-Factor, etc.

Comment: When you say username/password you're talking about the master username/password for the RDS instance right? I see that this is considered much safer to have one login and to be blocked off everything by the IP firewall unless you add yourself in it... Is this a good thing?

Comment: @user805981 You can create more users than just the master user. Once you are connected as the master user you can create as many DB user accounts as you want.

Answer (score 8):

It is now possible for MySQL or Amazon Aurora:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Comment: It would be useful if you could demonstrate how to do that in the answer itself.

Comment: Have you had any luck with that? There's no checkbox for enabling IAM in my database options

Comment: from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

MySQL 5.6, minor version 5.6.34 or higher
MySQL 5.7, minor version 5.7.16 or higher
Amazon Aurora 1.10 or higher

Answer (score 0):

See this gist with code example and notes on authenticating MySQL via PHP to Amazon Aurora using IAM:

https://gist.github.com/sators/38dbe25f655f1c783cb2c49e9873d58a

Comment: Hi, 
I used the code, but token generated via PHP SDK v/s the token from `aws rds generate-db-auth-token` cmd line seem to be different in length. I tried generating token via Java SDK too, same issue. Only cmd line RDS token generation works me ? Any idea if I need to change any policy on MySQL aurora side ?